# Navigation(slider) active status

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, slider

I would like to build a navigation with a forwoard- and backwoard-button. For example, if I click on forword or rather on backworad the menu point move one forward(like a image-slider).

But it should be allowed to click directly on each button. And the button should be on hover orange and in the active status also orange.

Here is an example:
[image]

Here is my navigation(html):

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li id="icon-back">
        <a href="#" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-backward fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Home" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Info" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Projects" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-code fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Contact" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="icon-for">
        <a href="#" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-forward fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and my CSS:

```
/******************************************* 
        Links
*******************************************/

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link:before {
    font-family:'Iceland';
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
}

a:visited {
    color: #666;
}

a:hover {
    color: #F90;
}

a:active {
    color: #F90;
}

/******************************************* 
            Navigation    
*******************************************/

    nav {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #333;
    clear: both;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #333 8%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white, #333 8%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #333 ´8%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(white, #333 8%); /* Standard syntax */
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

#icon-back {
    margin-right: 100px;   
}

#icon-for {
    margin-left: 60px;   
}
```

**e: Here is my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/13r07wwp/**

I hope, you will understand my problem. Sorry for my poor english. :D

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please

Comment: Do you think that when you click on contact button, full page will move on contact page? I think I know what you mean. In my opinion it's possible in AJAX

Comment: jsfiddel: done ( How do I create more than just one html page?)
@Honza Sedlon: The hover should work on all buttons, but the active status only on: Home, Info, Projects and Contact for example. Yeah, and if I click directly on the "contact button" the page should go to the contact page and the contact button should be active.